# Jquery not loading properly

Tags: jquery

I have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/g412rft4/1/ which as you can see works perfectly.

However I am trying to replicate it on my desktop with a test.html file and a Common.js file as well and it doesn't works. It seems like Jquery is never loaded and I don't get why.

This is the code for the .js file:

```
$( "#SaeReplacerBuilder" ).click(function() {
  alert("ok");
});
```

And this is the code for the .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Whatever</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="Common.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="SaeReplacerBuilder" style="background-color:#A0A0AA;border-radius:15px;padding-right:7px;padding-left:7px;border:2px solid #FF0000;color:#000000;">'''CLICK Here'''</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can load the jquery from here: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`. This is the latest version, from the Google API. Also, if you are not doing this on a website, that is, you are using a file on your computer, if you are not online the jquery will not load.

Comment: wrap the code in `$(function(){ /* code here*/})`. This is pretty basic for all jQuery. Your code is running before elememts exist

Comment: Yup it works now. Thank you, both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `Common.js` Javascript file is run the document looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Whatever</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="Common.js"></script>
```

You have to wait until the document has fully loaded before adding click handlers. jQuery gives you a way to easily do that:

```
$(function () { // This function will be run when the document is done loading
    $( "#SaeReplacerBuilder" ).click(function() {
        alert("ok");
    });
});
```

Further more, it is generally a good idea to put your Javascript near the bottom of your HTML code, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Whatever</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="SaeReplacerBuilder" style="background-color:#A0A0AA;border-radius:15px;padding-right:7px;padding-left:7px;border:2px solid #FF0000;color:#000000;">'''CLICK Here'''</div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Common.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Putting it in the `<head>` stops the rendering of the website until the Javascript file has been loaded. Putting it near the bottom allows the website to render the content (which is usually very fast) before the Javascript is loaded, which makes the website appear to load faster.

Answer (score 3):

Protocol-relative links (those that begin with `//`) only work when the page is being served by a web server. I'm assuming you're just viewing the file from your hard-drive.

Add a protocol and it would work:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js
```

If what you've shown is the exact contents of your Common.js file, you need to either:

a) Wrap the code in a ready event:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#SaeReplacerBuilder" ).click(function() {
        alert("ok");
    });
})
```

b) Move your Common.js script to the bottom of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Whatever</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="SaeReplacerBuilder" style="background-color:#A0A0AA;border-radius:15px;padding-right:7px;padding-left:7px;border:2px solid #FF0000;color:#000000;">'''CLICK Here'''</div>
        <script src="Common.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, you're attempting to bind a click event before the DOM is ready. I normally do both (use the ready event *and* move the scripts to the bottom), just to be safe.

Comment: Made that change. Still doesn't works. And yes i'm just viewing from my hard-drive.

Comment: Is the code in Common.js exactly what's shown after "This is the code for the .js file"? If so, you need to also wrap your code in the ready event handler that @charlietfl mentions.

Comment: Uhm... can you explain why it works in the jsfiddle without that change then? And yes, both files are **exactly** as shown.

Comment: Order. jsFiddle is arranging your references in the correct order for you when it builds the results iframe.

Answer (score 1):

The script tag needs to be relative to your html file, and I'm guessing this isn't loading locally:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

Try adding the protocol like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, script loaded by **script** tag doesn't run in a navigator context when loaded from a file://

You have to upload it on a real server and acces it with http://